# asymptotic notation for a multi-function variable

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I have read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables), but I am not yet sure. If I have a function as:

```
f(n, m) = n * m
```

is it correct to say its complexity is **O(mn)**?

Comment: Wouldn't this be O(1) because a multiplication operation is most likely a constant time operation that will not be affected by the size of the operands?

Comment: No, the growth of my complexity is actually dependent on both n and m.

Comment: In the example you have given, the definition of f() does not suggest that.

Comment: oh, ya. I checked it again and you are right it is O(1). thanks

Comment: No problem, I wanted to expand more on my answer but didn't have the time.